# how to parse XML with ASIHTTP

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser, asihttprequest

I am currently testing how to combine ios, php, mysql and xml. So far I have set up a database, got my php scripts working and am using them to request data from my external mysql database that then returns the results to my app using ASIHTTPRequest network wrappers.. what I am now trying to do is parse the xml that I am generating with my php scripts, Its a pretty easy example my php looks a little something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entries>
        <code>3237554</code>
</entries>
```

All I am looking to parse is that number, In the past I have use NSXMLParse from the objective-c library however I was calling everything from an rss feed so the set up to acquiring the data was entirely different as it was not self generated etc. Due to the fact that I am using ASIHTTPRequest I am taking a guess here 'that I would hopefully like you to help me with' is that I should be grabbing my xml in

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

which is pretty obvious because I am grabbing just basic text output from there as it is now.. So my question is what is the best way to start parsing this text thats coming in? is there a special xml parser library I am not aware of or can I use NSXMLParser some how?

//EDIT:: Working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576846/using-nsxmlparser-with-asihttprequest-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of the returned xml is not that big, libxml2 is a nice convenient solution that I have used effectively.

Take a look at Matt's blog here --

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html

Comment: Very nice tutorial, for the moment however because I plan on returning large sets of results I will need to learn the usual way :( however this is very good for another app I want to test out. Thank you.